# How to update one dynamically element of an array

Tags: reactjs

I have a state in my component like

```
const [game,setGame] = useState([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
```

and when i am trying to update it i am not able to do it.
I am trying

```
setGame([...game,{clickedBox:'red'}])
```

I am getting index in clickedBox

Comment: expected output?

Comment: Suppose i have 1 value in clickedBox so game array will be like [0,'red',0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: That's not how destructuring works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting in useState replaces the entire data it holds.
Update your array externally first, then set it back to your state.

```
let arr = [...game];
arr[index] = { /* your changes */ };
setGame([...arr)];
```